# Magento 1.9 combine discount amount and subtotal

Tags: magento

I'm looking for a way to change the subtotal before grandtotal in checkout and cart.
I want to hide the discount amount and add this to the final subtotal like this:

Current View:

```
Produkt #1 Price(10$) qty(2) subtotal(20$)
_____________________________
Subtotal 20$
discount -5$
shipping 5$
tax 0$
grandtotal 20$
```

**What I want**

```
Produkt #1 Price(10$) qty(2) subtotal(20$)
_____________________________
Subtotal 15$
shipping 5$
tax 0$
grandtotal 20$
```

I hope someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Use observer, You must recalculate all value and save.